# linux pl011 serial driver: do not output after open /dev/console

Tags: linux, serial-port, arm, kernel

I am porting linux to a customize board that using a ARM Primecell pl011 serial IP core.

- Linux version is 4.7.0-rc1+.
- I am not using DMA engine.
- I am using devtmpfs
- I specified boot parameter "console=ttyAMA0"
- The startup log is outputted well before open /dev/console
- the output will stop after open /dev/console

init/main.c:kernel_init_freeable()

```
[...]
printk("open /dev/console\n");       // <- this will be outputted
/* Open the /dev/console on the rootfs, this should never fail */
if (sys_open((const char __user *) "/dev/console", O_RDWR, 0) < 0)
    pr_err("Warning: unable to open an initial console.\n");
printk("opened /dev/console\n");       // <- this will not be outputted
[...]
```

any hints are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit!!!
clock frequency setting in DTS is wrong.
I guess the driver using wrong clock and the output can be seen by chance.(I did not specified a baudrate in bootargs, that is only "console=ttyAMA0")
When I changed clock frequency in DTS to right one. all things are perfect now!!!